# how to add Language in drupal 7.09

Tags: drupal-7

I have added language for french but not working i got the issues,how to add language please help me

EntityMetadataWrapperException: Invalid data value given. Be sure it matches the required data type and format. Value at node(): . in EntityDrupalWrapper->set() (line 765 of /var/www/html/xmbo/sites/all/modules/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc).